# Windows limit CPU usage using JobObject not working on all computers

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cpu-usage

I am using JobObject to limit my process cpu usage. I am running my code on two computers running windows 10. On one machine it's working but on the other it's not working although all WINAPI calls return successfully. This my code:

```
string jobName = "test_job";
HANDLE hJobObject = NULL;
hJobObject = CreateJobObject(NULL, jobName.c_str());
if (hJobObject == NULL) {
    return -1;
}

JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION cpuRateInfo; 
cpuRateInfo.ControlFlags = JOB_OBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_ENABLE | JOB_OBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_HARD_CAP;
cpuRateInfo.CpuRate = 10 * 100;
if (!SetInformationJobObject(hJobObject, JobObjectCpuRateControlInformation, &cpuRateInfo, sizeof(JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION))) {
    return -1;
}

HANDLE currentProcessHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(hJobObject, currentProcessHandle)) {
    return -1;
}
```

Any idea what cause this issue?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by not working. Is it limited to less or more than 10%, or not at all?

Comment: Not limited at all

Answer (score 1):

You should first verify that the current process works under an existing job control.

Add these lines of code：

```
BOOL bInJob = FALSE;
IsProcessInJob(GetCurrentProcess(),NULL,&bInJob);
if (bInJob)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,L"Process is in Job!",TEXT(""),MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Since a process belongs to one job object, it cannot be assigned to another job object.

> In addition, In Windows-enabled `UAC` systems, processes without
>   prompt privileges are added to a default compatibility system
>   `JobObject`, so a process must be created using the
>   `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` parameter to separate the process from the
>   default `JobObject`.

Hope to help you.

Comment: The question relates to a Windows 10 system. Windows 8 and later allow nested jobs.